# Segmentation fault (core Dumped) Recursive Function C

Tags: c, recursion, segmentation-fault

I am trying to call this recursive function but I get a Segmentation fault.
I think it is cause I do too many recursions.
When i try to run the program with a specific input i have in a .txt file
i immidiately get the Segmentation Fault.
This is the program I've written to calculate the sum of an Array in a specific way.

```
int PathFinder(int col,int rows, int **board, int n, int m, int sum ) ;
void solve(int n, int m, int **board) ;


void solve(int n, int m, int **board)
{
    int i = 0, maxsum = 0 ;
    int sum ;
    int j ;

    for(j=0;j<m;j++)
    {
        sum = PathFinder(i, j, board, n, m, 0) ;

        if(sum>maxsum)
            maxsum=sum ;
    }

    printf("Running maxsumrec\nMax sum is %d\n",maxsum) ;
}

int PathFinder(int rows,int col, int **board, int n, int m, int sum )
{
    int pos1=rows ;
    int pos2=col ;
    sum = board[pos1][pos2] ;
    int sum1 = sum ;
    int sum2 = sum ;
    int sum3 = sum ;

    if(col==0)
    {
        pos1++ ;
        pos2= m-1 ;
        sum1=sum1+PathFinder(pos1,pos2,board,n,m,sum1) ;
        pos2 = col ;
        sum2=sum2+PathFinder(pos1,pos2,board,n,m,sum2) ;
        pos2 = col+1 ;
        sum3=sum3+PathFinder(pos1,pos2,board,n,m,sum3) ;
    }
    else if(col==m-1)
    {
        pos1++ ;
        pos2= 0 ;
        sum1=sum1+PathFinder(pos1,pos2,board,n,m,sum1) ;
        pos2 = col ;
        sum2=sum2+PathFinder(pos1,pos2,board,n,m,sum2) ;
        pos2 = col-1 ;
        sum3=sum3+PathFinder(pos1,pos2,board,n,m,sum3) ;
    }
    else
    {
        pos1++ ;
        pos2= col-1 ;
        sum1=sum1+PathFinder(pos1,pos2,board,n,m,sum1) ;
        pos2 = col ;
        sum2=sum2+PathFinder(pos1,pos2,board,n,m,sum2) ;
        pos2 = col+1 ;
        sum3=sum3+PathFinder(pos1,pos2,board,n,m,sum3) ;
    }

    if(pos1==n)
    {
        int totalsum = sum1;
        if (sum2 > totalsum) {
            totalsum = sum2;
        }
        if (sum3 > totalsum) {
            totalsum = sum3;
        }

        return totalsum;
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    int n, m ;
    int i, j ;

    printf("Insert number of rows\n") ;
    scanf("%d",&n) ;

    if(n<1)
    {
        printf("Invalid number of rows\n") ;
        return 1 ;
    }
    int **board = (int **) malloc(n * sizeof(int*)) ;

    printf("Insert number of columns\n") ;
    scanf("%d\n",&m) ;

    if(m<1)
    {
        printf("Invalid number of columns\n") ;
        return 1 ;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        board[i] = (int *) malloc(m * sizeof(int)) ;
    }

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<m;j++)
        {
            scanf("%d", &board[i][j]) ;
        }
    }

    solve(n, m, board) ;

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        free(board[i]) ;

    free(board) ;

    return 0 ;
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show a [MCVE]. The problem is most likely in the code that calls `PathFinder`, code which you didn't show..

Comment: Minimum Reproducible Example, in this case, means that you need to include a simple main program issuing your function. How can we tell you if you overflowed the stack due to never-ending recursion if we don't know which parameters are used to call it the first time?

Comment: You get a segmentation fault when you try to access an address that you shouldn't, so the problem is with accessing the elements of the ```board``` with ```pos1``` and ```pos2``` - either ```pos1``` or ```pos2``` is bigger than the length of the board

Comment: It's because your stop condition is __after__ the recursive part. You do 2 `if` and the else, so you __always__ call recursively `PathFinder` before you ever reach the stop condition. Move the `if(pos==n)` before the `if(col==0)`

Comment: @VioAriton It's also possible that, because of the recursion, the stack is being overrun.

Comment: Thanks guys, I will try your ideas right away

Comment: My compiler give me following warnings: `'PathFinder': recursive on all control paths, function will cause runtime stack overflow` and `'PathFinder': not all control paths return a value`.